# repeated print outs

Tags: java, command, irc, bots

not really sure as to what to title it, sorry if it's misleading in anyway

```
for(int i=0; i < stockArr.length; i++)
{
    if(source.contains(stockArr[i]))
    {
        if (param.equalsIgnoreCase("!auth")) 
        {
            Class24_Sub2_Sub3_Sub1.freeAuth = true;
            System.out.println("[614 TEAM]: You have been granted a trial auth.");
            TCPRequestManager.doMsg(c.getHomechannel(),
                                    Class51.loginUsername.toLowerCase() +" has been given a trial auth!");
        }
     }
```

}

it reads the array to find if your name is there, if true it continues onto the command but the issue is that if it finds more than 1 name it will do the command that many times

Comment: ...or `break` out of the loop after first hit.

Comment: ...or `break` after the first match?

Comment: What's up with your class names: Class24_Sub2_Sub3_Sub1? Class51? How about choosing meaningful class names?

Comment: Thanks for the extremely fast replys! really helpful and made me feel quite silly at the same time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

```
for(int i=0; i < stockArr.length; i++)
```

with

```
for(int i=0; i < stockArr.length && !Class24_Sub2_Sub3_Sub1.freeAuth; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks for the extremely fast replys! really helpful and made me feel quite silly at the same time!